# Problem in setting an empty array with array of objects after an async api using setter function call in react hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I'm using next.js 10.
I want to populate `deliveryAddressArray` after page is mounted. I can't find what I'm missing here.

Here is my address.js page

```
const [deliveryAddressArray, setDeliveryAddressArray] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    
    async function getDeliveryAddressArray() {
      try {
        const response = await axios({
          method: "get",
          url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos",
        });
        setDeliveryAddressArray(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    }
    getDeliveryAddressArray();
  }, []);

return (
    <>
      . . . some other code . . .
            <Select
                showSearch
                allowClear
                style={{ width: 200 }}
                placeholder="Select a location"
            >
                { deliveryAddressArray.map((value) => {
                    return (
                        <Option value={value.title}>{value.title}</Option>
                    );
                })}
            </Select>
     </>
  );
};

export default address;
```

my api response array is

```
[
   {
      "userId":1,
      "id":1,
      "title":"delectus aut autem",
      "completed":false
   },
   {
      "userId":1,
      "id":2,
      "title":"quis ut nam facilis et officia qui",
      "completed":false
   },
   {
      "userId":1,
      "id":3,
      "title":"fugiat veniam minus",
      "completed":false
   },
   .....
]
```

This is the error I'm facing

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {userId, id, title, completed}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

Comment: what you return from address.js ?

Comment: Where is `deliveryAddressArray` used in your code? Can you please show the full code for that page?

Comment: I have updated my question with detailed `address.js` component. could  you please check ?

Comment: @juliomalves any solution yet ?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the code you shared. Are you sure you're not using `deliveryAddressArray` anywhere else?

Comment: @juliomalves yes I am

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment on your question yet but it does requires clarification.

I do have an answer though: The error you are mentioning is a rendering error so there must be something wrong with how you use `deliveryAddressArray` in the render function of your component.

Comment: error is throwing from this line 
`setDeliveryAddressArray(response.data)`

and I'm not using `deliveryAddressArray` in the render function. I'm not even mapping the array in dom. I'm getting error while I set the value of array before even render in dom.

Comment: Can you update `address.js` page with the whole content? I don't see here what could be the issue.

Comment: I have updated my question with detailed `address.js` component. could you please check ?

Comment: Have you tried to log what is in your array before the return function?

Comment: I did. All looks well. I get the response as expected.

Comment: Okay, still cryptic... It might be an issue with the `Select` and `Option` components ? Where do you import those from ?

Comment: from Ant Design